# Function fires twice on event

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Somehow function **showMore()** fires twice when I get to the end of the slides list. It has something to do with conditional rendering where **loadingMorePosts** is being checked because when I delete this line of code the function triggers only once. How can I fix it?

```
const PostList: FC = () => {

    const [postsData, setPostsData] = useState<TPost[] | undefined>();
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [loadingMorePosts, setLoadingMorePosts] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const showMore = () => {
        setLoadingMorePosts(true);
        console.log("SHOWMORE");
        setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // getPostsFromServer()
        getPosts(page)
        .then(newPosts => newPosts.json() as Promise<TPostData>)
        .then(newPosts => {

            setPostsData(prevState => [...(prevState ?? []), ...newPosts.posts]);
            setLoading(false);
            setLoadingMorePosts(false);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e.message);
            setError(true);
            setLoading(false);
        })
    }, [page]);

    if (loading) return <Spinner />;

    return (
        <div className="post-list">
            <div className="post-list__menu">

                <div className="post-list__menu-left">
                    <span>user stories</span>
                    <span className='disabled'>last change<span className='sticker'>soon</span></span>
                </div>

                <AddStoryModal />
            </div>
            <div className='post-list__postitem-view'>
                <Swiper
                    spaceBetween={10}
                    slidesPerView={"auto"}
                    grabCursor={true}
                    touchMoveStopPropagation={true}
                    onReachEnd={showMore}
                >

                    {error ? <ErrorSign /> : postsData?.map((post: TPost) => {
                        return <SwiperSlide key={post.id}>
                            <PostItem key={post.id} title={post.title} body={post.body} userId={post.userId} id={post.id} />
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    })}

                    {loadingMorePosts && <SwiperSlide className='post-item-spinner' key={"spinner"}><Spinner /></SwiperSlide>}
                </Swiper>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a useRef hook to keep track of whether the showMore function is currently being executed. This will prevent the function from being called multiple times while it is still running.

```
const isShowMoreRunning = useRef(false);

const showMore = () => {
  if (!isShowMoreRunning.current) {
    isShowMoreRunning.current = true;
    setLoadingMorePosts(true);
    setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  isShowMoreRunning.current = false;
}, [postsData]);

<Swiper
  ...
  onReachEnd={showMore}
>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks a lot. I spent a whole day trying to figure this out. Do you mind explaining a bit why it doesn't work without ref?